# How do set a break in my html text in @media?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a page which I want to justify the text in mobile, and split the text up and justify in desktop. At the moment mobile view is fine but text refuses to `text-align: justify;` and desktop is fine except I want to break the line `Adsler is a classified listings company established in 2018.`  in two equal parts and then justify

Html:

```
<div class="a"> A </h1></div><div class="boutus"> bout 
</div><div class="boutustext">Adsler is a classified 
listings company established in 2018.</div>
```

Page: https://adsler.co.uk/about-adsler/

Comment: As you have used text-align:left!important in desktop you need to override that using mediaqueries for mobile resolution.

Comment: Thanks. But I only `text-align: left;` because `text-align: justify;` didn't work. It didn't work altogether, at all.

Comment: Please show your CSS here, in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1). Use `<br>` with a class such as `<br class="mobile-br">`

Set that in between the text you want to split:

```
<div class="boutustext">Adsler is a classified 
<br class="mobile-br">
listings company established in 2018.</div>
```

Step 2). hide the `<br>` in your CSS media query for **desktop** using:

```
.mobile-br {
display:none;
}
```

And for mobile:

```
.mobile-br{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean hide it in mobile? Mobile is already split as i want.  So split text in html, then use @media query below 768px to hide? Like so: `@media (max-width: 768px) {.mobile-br {display: none;}}` This way it just applies to desktop?

Comment: I'll mark correct as basically right together with my comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this, Marcus' is one option, here's how I'd do it.

Wrap your two lines in spans.

code:

```css
.boutustext {
  text-align: justify;
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
  /*Or whatever your breakpoint is*/
  .boutustext span {
    display: block;
    text-align: justify;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="boutustext">
  <span>Adsler is a classified</span>
  <span>listings company established in 2018.</span>
</div>
```

The spans will be by default displayed inline and affected by your justify text, but then on mobile they will display as block elements, which will wrap.

Bear in mind that the justify may or may not obviously display, it depends on how the width of the text compares to the width of the container. If it's too short then it's not going to try to fill the width of it.